# Simple Html Dom Scraping half the page

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape this url https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart/ using simple-html-dom, but it does not seem to get the full html source code. This code:

```
        include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = file_get_html('https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart');

        echo $html->plaintext;
```

displays the content up to the h1, just before the content I am after. And from the simple-html-dom manual examples, this should display all links from that url:

```
        foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
        echo $e->href . '<br>';
```

but it only displays the links up to the main navigation menu, not from the main body or footer.

I also tried using prerender.com, to fully load url before passing it to file_get_html but the result was the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Viewing the raw source of https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart/ (and not the dom inspector) shows the data you're trying to fetch is there.

Comment: exactly. so why does not simple-html-dom not working with this page?

Comment: Are you trying to get a whole HTML layout or the raw data that went into that table?

Comment: I am trying to get the chart data: Ranking Number, Artist, Title, Youtube Link. There are even id's for each one, so this should have not been a problem with simple-html-dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my super dirty approach to fetching the rank/artist/title/youtube data using both DOMDocument and SimpleXML.

The concept is to locate each "row" of data via the xpath `//ul[@id="chart_ul"]/li`, then using `dom_import_simplexml( $outer )->getNodePath()` to build a new xpath to select the individual elements where the desired data can be located.

```
$temp = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'nrg-airplay-chart.html';

if( file_exists( $temp ) === false or filemtime( $temp ) < time() - 3600 )
{
  file_put_contents( $temp, $html = file_get_contents('https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart/') );
}
else
{
  $html = file_get_contents( $temp );
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xml = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
$array = array();

foreach( $xml->xpath('//ul[@id="chart_ul"]/li') as $index => $set )
{
  $basexpath = dom_import_simplexml( $set )->getNodePath();
  $array[] = array(
    'ranking' => (string) $xml->xpath( $basexpath . '//span[@id="ranking"]' )[0],
    'artist' => (string) $xml->xpath( $basexpath . '//p[@id="artist"]/b' )[0],
    'title' => (string) $xml->xpath( $basexpath . '//p[@id="title"]' )[0],
    'youtube' => (string) $xml->xpath( $basexpath . '//div[@id="media"]/a/@href' )[0],
  );
}

print_r( $array );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated. I will be testing your code soon.

Answer (score 3):

That library looks like it hasn't been updated in 7 years. I'd always recommend using [PHP's built-in functions](http://php.net/DomDocument):

```
$url = "https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart/";
$dom = new DomDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->load($url);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $e) {
    echo $e->getAttribute("href") . "\n";
}
```

Comment: FYI, the _real_ URL is `https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart/` (trailing slash). The former redirects to the latter so you can save an HTTP request

Comment: And yes, Simple HTML DOM is trash :)

Comment: I thought simple-html-dom was the proper way for parsing/scraping. Thank you for your reply, I will probably be using your DOMDocument approach.

Comment: Seems Simple HTML DOM half works and PHP's built-in functions don't work at all. Sad.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you might wanna comply:

```
<?php
    function get_content($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $htmlContent;
    }
    $link = "https://nrg91.gr/nrg-airplay-chart/"; 
    $xml = get_content($link);

    $dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach($xpath->query('//li[contains(@id,"wprs_chart-")]') as $items){
        $artist = $xpath->query('.//p[@id="artist"]/b',$items)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $title = $xpath->query('.//p[@id="title"]',$items)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo "{$artist} -- {$title}<br>";
    }
?>
```

Output you should get like:

```
PORTOGAL THE MAN -- Feel It Still
JAX JONEW Feat INA WROLDSEN -- Breathe
CAMILA CABELLO -- Havana
CARBI B, J BALVIN & BAD BUNNY -- I Like It
ZAYN Feat SIA -- Dusk Till Dawn
```

Comment: Great, I will be trying your code too. Thank you for your reply!